# Need strategy for passing ID's in AJAX to backend logic

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

This is more of a general design question I guess...
I have an Ajax application that displays a table listing purchase orders.
Each order has a checkbox next to it

The idea is to check some of them, then press a button and a JavaScript function will start, pulling out the "checked" ones and passing them server side.

Right now the best I could come up with is giving each check-box a "value" attribute with the ACTUAL ORDER identifying number. So when they are collected, and passed to the controller, I can just use the values to query the database for the exact orders.

But I have a nagging feeling that this is not secure and not the most efficient way to do this.

So I would love to hear the better ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your users already require (and have) a session, I don't see a problem with just sending the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the orders list can see only certain user, I dont see anything bad in your pattern.
In other hand, if someone could get this id and do request with it(for example - to delete order), you can always chack the permissions on server-side.

Answer (score 0):

secure, in what way wouldn't that be secure ? does it matter the clients get to see those id's ?

Certain users shouldn't be able to pass any purchase order to the server ?

Yes, I think my last question is your answer.

And about it being inefficient; is there a performance problem with your approach ?

Comment: So far no such issues. I am just curious how other developers would approach such a requirement.

Comment: well, if there are no issues, it's al good. It's a good idea to work with the id's; it's short and always correct; the id's won't change, names or other things might.